# What is the differnce between "using" and an "assembly"?

Tags: xamarin.essentials

when I was using Xamarin.Essentials, I needed to add an assembly reference. What is the difference between them? I though both were references. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an assembly A references an assembly B, then A can use all public types that are contained in B. So it's all about making the contents of another assembly known to your assembly.

The `using` keyword is used within source files to conveniently allow you to refer to types within a certain namespace without having to specify their full name.

You can access any type without `using` by specifying their full name like

```
void MyMethod()
{
    var myList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
}
```

But if you put a `using` statement into your source, you can refer to the type more easily like

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

void MyMethod()
{
    var myList = new List<int>();
}
```

So `using` is really only a convenience feature to make your code more easily written and read.